# Add new column to data frame by mapping over existing one

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I'm trying to add a new column to my data frame by mapping over an existing column using `lapply`, but I'm having a surprisingly difficult time.

My data frame has a column called "status", and each of its elements is either "Compile Error", "Wrong Answer", "Time Limit Exceeded", "Runtime Error", or "Accepted".

I'd like to create a new column called "accepted", where its elements are 1 if its status is "Accepted", and 0 if otherwise. So, this seemed like a good use for `lapply`, as shown here:

```r
codeAnnotations$accepted <- codeAnnotations["status"] %>%
    lapply(function(x) ifelse(x == "Accepted", 1, 0))
```

However, it seems its actually filling each row of "accepted" with the whole mapped "status" column:

| status (chr) | accepted (list) |
| --- | --- |
| Accepted | <dbl [6,506]> |

And indeed, there are 6,506 rows in my data table.

Is there any reason why `lapply` is behaving like this? Is there another way to create a new column by mapping over an existing one?

Comment: Please share a reproducible sample of your data set with `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: Why not this? `codeAnnotations$accepted <- ifelse(codeAnnotations$status  == "Accepted", 1, 0)`.

Comment: `lapply()` always outputs a `list()`. Your code is assigning the same one-element list to each element of the "accepted" variable in the data.frame.  But it sounds like you really want to just use `ifelse()` without `lapply'.  `ifelse()` is vectorized and will give you a single value for each row in the data.frame (i.e., a vector instead of a list).

Comment: That worked beautifully! You're absolutely right, I forgot about `ifelse()` being vectorised. Thank you very much indeed